# [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in field definition

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

I am accessing an Access database inside a java program, however I get an error when I execute the sql command:

```
static String SQLCreate = "CREATE TABLE CONTACT_INFO (" +
        "Contact_ID INTERGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
        "First_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL," +
        "MI CHAR(1)," +
        "Last_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL," +
        "Street VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL," +
        "City VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL," +
        "ZIP VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);";
```

I cant see anything wrong, maybe a new set of eyes will help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. Replace `INTERGER` with `INTEGER` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I needed some fresh eyes.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?